# Regexp for completing the latex command

Tags: python, tex

Ok, I want to use regular expressions for changing my `.tex` file.

I have next patterns: `'\mathcal{ <some letter>'` without ending second brace. I need to glue it to `<some letter>` from the right side. Note that I have **white space** after first brace.

I've done this regexp:

```
import sys
import re

with open('output.tex', 'w') as out:
    with open('input.tex', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            newline = re.sub('mathcal{..?', 'mathcal{\\1}', line)
            out.write(newline)
```

but it seems not to work with the error "**invalid group reference 1 at position 9**". How to make it right?

**Example:** so to the input: `Let $f$ --- choice function, given on $\mathcal{ B$`. I want it to be: `Let $f$ --- choice function, given on $\mathcal{ B}$`

Comment: Could you edit your post with an example input and expected output?

Comment: @PaulM., ok, I'll do it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for editing your question. I'm not familiar with latex, but it seems like you just want to use a regex to insert a `}` between the single uppercase character and the `$`. Let me know if this solution isn't general enough:

```
import re

line = "Let $f$ --- choice function, given on $\mathcal{ B$"

pattern = "mathcal{ ([A-Z])\\$"

new_line = re.sub(pattern, "mathcal{ \\1}$", line)
print(new_line)
```

Output:

```
Let $f$ --- choice function, given on $\mathcal{ B}$
>>>
```

Comment: From start it wasn't correct, since it was ```"mathcal{ \\1}\\$"```, but now it's fine. However it works not for all cases, but I think it's valid and would be ambigious to amke a regexp handling all of the cases. Thanks!